# Gmap3: Unable to use custom style for Google Map

Tags: google-maps-api-3, jquery-gmap3

I'm using the jQuery Plugin [GMAP3](http://gmap3.net) to display a map with a number of markers on my website.

I know that the Google Maps API V3 [allows](http://code.google.com/intl/en-EN/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/styling.html#styling_the_default_map) custom styling of Maps, I just can't figure out how to use this feature with GMAP3. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In gmap3 api docs, there is an example about how to use styled map, you can check it out
[here](http://gmap3.net/en/catalog/15-map-types/styledmaptype-56).

Comment: the link have already changed to http://gmap3.net/en/catalog/15-map-types/styledmaptype-56

Answer (score 0):

Check out the setOptions function for the map object.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#

If this still wont  work you may try making the styled map outside of gmap3 first.

Answer (score 0):

The Best Custom styles you can make/ understand from here:[Google Custom Style Link](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html?utm_medium=twitter)